# LyX citation styles after insertion

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, citing

I'm using LyX with the bibliography set to `natbib` > `Author, Year` in Document Settings and `plainnat` in the bibliography settings. So far, so good. This has the desired effect within the bibliography and the citations look good, with one exception - they are not surrounded with brackets, so they appear in the text as just `Cited, 2006` rather than `(Cited, 2006)`.

This seems to be because I was using the Default (numerical) setting until now, and changing to `natbib` has given the 'insert citation' dialogue multiple citation styles. Every one of my 250+ citations has now defaulted to the style without brackets.

So, question:

- Is it possible to change all citation styles in one go?
- Is it possible to change the `natbib` behaviour someway to put the brackets in (like the `\bibpunct` preamble or something?)

Any help much appreciated! Worst case scenario I'll go back to numerical citations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it - I opened the `.lyx` file in a text editor (TextMate, but any would do) and did a find and replace to change the citation style of every citation.

- *Find:* **`LatexCommand cite`**
- *Replace:* **`LatexCommand citep`**

That extra **`p`** makes all of the difference! Probably worth a second find and replace to make sure there are no instances of **`citepp`**, and definitely worth doing a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are under *nix, or have cygwin installed, consider a script

```
 sed "s/LatexCommand\ cite/LatexCommand\ citep/g" yourfile.lyx > newfile.tex
```

with obvious replacements for `yourfile` and `newfile`.

Comment: +1 for reminding us that Linux terminal does not bite.